# How Add Control to web page in Application_Start event

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, global-asax

Is it possible to add control to a page in Application_Start Project?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. No *form* exist at this stage of the application lifecycle. And in IIS Integrated mode you don't even have access to HttpContext objects such as Request, Response, Session, ... So talking about controls and forms in Application_Start simply doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at the top of the page as something like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="links" Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
```